# Screen resolution on KDE and Windows

Tags: windows, cross-platform, screen-resolution, kde4

I was developing a small application using Qt4 to get it cross-platform, but when I compared the result I found a really disturbing issue.

On both Linux (KDE4) and Windows 7 my screen resolution is `1680 x 1050` but on KDE my application widgets are bigger and there is not enough place to have both important widgets opened without one being partially hidden. It just looks as if the real resolution is smaller on Linux.

Do you have any ideas what is the cause of such situation and if there is any way to handle it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the operating systems window managers theme.

By default Qt will use the operating systems style to ensure a constant look and feel with the underlying OS.

You can adjust this by setting the style of your application:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html